# How to align different plots xticks/figure size (one plot from matplotlib , another from seaborn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I wrote a example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(42)
feature = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range('20200101', periods=100*24, freq='H'), 
                        'y': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'yhat': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'price': np.random.choice([6600, 7000, 5500, 7800], 100*24)})

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(16,16),'font.family': 'WenQuanYi Micro Hei'})
f = plt.figure()

a = feature.set_index('ds').resample('D').sum()

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('销量')

x_dates = feature['ds'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').sort_values().unique()

plt.plot(x_dates, a['y'], label='实际销量')
plt.plot(x_dates, a['yhat'], label='预测销量')

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(x_dates.shape[0])[::2])
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates[::2], rotation=45, ha='right')


plt.legend()

ax3 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('价格箱型图')
date_feature = feature.assign(date=lambda df:df.ds.dt.date)
sns.boxplot(x=date_feature['date'], y=date_feature['price'], ax=ax3)
ax3.set_xticks(np.arange(x_dates.shape[0])[::2])
ax3.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates[::2], rotation=45, ha='right')
print(1)
```

You can see below picture, there are blanks in matplotlib's plot , how do I make xtick in each plot align vertical ?

[image]

PS: change `plt.plot` to `sns.lineplot` act same .

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution `xlim`

The lineplot actually doesn't respect the input x, it would add some value .
So what I should do is add same `xlim` for each plot :

```py
plt.xlim(-2, x_dates.shape[0] +2 )
```

Then xtcks are align vertical (though doesn't align to graph) :

[image]